# Core Data : Get Records where more than one objects available in relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have one Entity Category which can contain subcategories of the same type so I want only those categories which have more than 1 subcategory available.

Here is the schema of the entity.
[image: Schema]

Here is my code to get the details.

```
func getAllCategory() -> [TestCategory] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Category>(entityName: "\(Category.self)")
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "%K.count > %i","childCategories",0)
    do {
        let results = try self.getCurrentContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch  {
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600000a34a80> , to-many key not allowed here with userInfo of (null)
```

Thanks

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the issue is with your code or what your question is.

Comment: You want to filter out `Category`s that have > 1 `childCategory`?

Comment: Yes, Added error in the post. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems like you have the to-many-relationship one time too much. It seems like your childCategories have multiple parent categories. I had that issue before. Setting the relationship resp. the Destination and building again (letting Xcode create the necessary files) helped for me.